# Place recognition with WiFi

Tags: mobile, places

I'm looking for some algorithm able to better recognize the geometry place only exploiting wi-fi antennas. I read about place recognition is divided in two classes: geometry and fingerprint. I'm interested to use fingerprinting one and I'd like to develop an intelligent system able to learn more and more which is the correct set of right values (e.g. rssi, mac, response rate...) identify the place. I'm not interested to geo-referentiate the place but only to recognize the place. What kind of technique should I consider? Statistical learning (MLE, bayesian models...) or I can think to use classification algorithms like support vector machine or others? can I think to explore fuzzy system for my purpose?

Comment: This sounds like it belongs on the [stats site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions), not here.  We could migrate it for you, but it's certain to be closed as being too vague.  Please consider providing more information about your sources ("read about...") and the kinds of data you are expecting.

Comment: I find this question quite interesting and timely.  Microsoft is [being sued](http://www.washingtonpost.com/business/technology/woman-sues-microsoft-alleging-mobile-software-tracks-locations-after-users-opt-out/2011/09/01/gIQAX9y0uJ_story.html) ... certainly there will be people on the web searching for more technical details about [how they do geolocalization](http://elie.im/blog/privacy/using-the-microsoft-geolocalization-api-to-retrace-where-a-windows-laptop-has-been/).